# Bernstein uniform approximation by polynomials : What is $E_n(f)$?

Tags: interpolation, constants

I am having a difficult time understanding what Bernstein's constant is. Wikipedia states "Let $E_n(f)$ be the error of the best uniform approximation to a real function $f(x)$ in the interval $[-1, 1]$ by real polynomials of no more than degree $n$. In the case $f(x)=|x|$". What I am confused about is why $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2nE_{2n}(f)$$ is a constant and not a function. I thought that $E_n(f(x))=|f(x)-f_n(x)|$ where $f_n(x)$ is the best polynomial approximation. So, is there a more mathematical way to describe what $E_n(f)$ is or show some examples that makes it easier to understand what it is?

Comment: I would expect $E_n(f(x)) = \sup\{|f(x) - f_n(x)| : x \in [-1,1]\}$ which is a constant for each $n$ so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2nE_{2n}(f)$ is just a sequence.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to find $f_n$ though?

Comment: See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4152546/305862).

Comment: @KamalSaleh you may be interested in Bernstein Polynomials since they approximate functions well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thanks for the link but I can't visualize it properly. Desmos is telling me that Bernstein's constant doesn't exist unless I am doing something wrong: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dc4opdk0vr

Comment: @KamalSaleh you're plotting the error not the Bernstein polynomials. It won't look the same. You've also forgotten the supremum again.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I should've been more clear. I am plotting the error, but the supremum in the interval, which is the highest gray point(s), is growing too quickly to converge.

Comment: @KamalSaleh you can see clearly for $a=10$ that the highest point is less than $1$. It's not growing much at all. Don't forget that you're restricted to the interval $-1 \leq x \leq 1$. It grows outside that range.

Comment: For $a=10$, the highest point for me is $16$.